# Proof of infinitude of primes using the irrationality of π

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pi

According to the section [Proof using the irrationality of $\pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Proof_using_the_irrationality_of_.CF.80) of the Wikipedia article on Euclid's theorem, Euler proved that:

$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac34\cdot\frac54\cdot\frac78\cdot\frac{11}{12}\cdot\frac{13}{12}\cdots$$

where "each denominator is the multiple of four nearest to the numerator".
Can someone please explain this formula? I see it, but cannot believe it.

Comment: A very nice explanation is given here: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath477.htm

Comment: $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac11+\frac14+\frac19+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{25}+\cdots=\prod_{p} \frac{1}{1-p^{-2}}$$

Comment: @Makoto, it's related, but rather different.

Comment: @J.M. I know. I just thought it had something similar to the above.

Answer (score 10):

The formula is described [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/primenumbers/message/14486) (I am having a hard time finding a more authoritative reference); briefly, the OP's product in the usual product notation goes like

$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\prod_{k=2}^\infty \frac{p_k}{p_k-\chi(p_k)}$$

where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime and $\chi(n)$ is a character defined as

$$\chi(n)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }n\equiv 1\pmod 4\\-1&\text{if }n\equiv 3\pmod 4\end{cases}$$

As noted, the derivation is done by treating the usual Leibniz series

$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}$$

as a Dirichlet series, and then expanding that series as an [Euler product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product).

**Edit:** Daniel has given [another nice link](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath477.htm) in the comments.